# How to print outliers using a for-loop in R?

Tags: r, algorithm, for-loop, boxplot, outliers

I want to create an algorithm using a `for-loop` that returns the **lowest outlier** for each numeric (or integer) variable. Where the lowest outlier is defined by a boxplot i.e. : `boxplot.stats(dataframe[[n]])$out`.
And print a second string if no outliers exist within that numeric/integer column.

```
for(i in df){
  lowest <- ifelse(is.numeric(i), min(boxplot.stats(i)$out), "not numeric/integer")
  print(ifelse(lowest != "Inf", lowest, "No outliers"))
}
```

I have managed with this but I get the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In min(boxplot.stats(i)$out) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: What do you mean by "use an `if` and `else` statement instead"? Aren't you already using `ifelse()` to decide what to print?

Comment: Updated the question. I don't know how to share the data I'm afraid, fairly new to this.